# More poetic way to say "my feelings for you"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a shorter way, as well as a more poetic or "deeper" way of labeling emotional, loving feelings for someone?

What I'm trying to say is: 
*I refuse to undermine my feelings for you by being trite*

Comment: I makes me think to that Oscar Wilde quote: “*To be in love is to surpass one's self*".

Comment: Have you considered consulting any of a thousand different poets?  Good ol' Shakey is a good place to start: "Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?"

Comment: A "more poetic way for saying *my feelings for you*". Why does every answer contain the term *trite*. Is it obligatory? It's such an ugly-sounding word too. Trite can be substituted with *shallow*, *overused*, *banal* or *clichè*. Would you like a synonym  for *undermine my feelings*?

Answer (score 0):

"my esteem for you" or "my affection for you" . . . consider also whether what you are worried about "undermining" is not your own feelings, but rather the thing between the two of you ("our friendship" "our bond").

Answer (score 0):

Shorter? Well sheesh, love.

*I refuse to undermine my love for you by being trite*

Or am I being trite?

Answer (score 0):

From

> I refuse to undermine my feelings for you by being trite

to

> I refuse to quench the dazzling glimmers of your heart by being trite

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but it looks like you need a poet for this job!

> I refuse to belittle the depths of my affection by triteness.

or

> I shall not undermine the deep bond we share by being trite.

or Shakespeare-style:

> Were I to practise triteness, it would
>   Perchance reduce my deeply felt regard
>   For you, my heart. So I shall not:
>   Let triteness be the furthest from my mind.

I could make up a rhyming verse as well, but I think I'd expect a bounty for that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, a word about diction. I don't think you'd *undermine* the feelings by being trite. After all, your feelings would *not* be weakened by your use of trite language. Rather, you're afraid that commonplace language wouldn't do your intense feelings *justice*. You could say that your feelings surpass the bounds of ordinary language. Or you could say that you refuse to *betray* your feelings by being trite (using *betray* in the sense of *be disloyal to*)

*Passion*, though simple, is a strong synonym for intense emotional feelings, especially those tinged with eroticism.

- *I refuse to betray my passion for you by being trite*.
- *I refuse to betray my passion by being trite*.
- *I refuse to betray the depth and complexity of my passion by being trite.*

Comment: A "more poetic way for saying *my feelings for you*" Why does every answer contain the term *trite*. Is it obligatory? It's such an ugly-sounding word too.

Answer (score 0):

"I refuse to undermine my heart's sincere affection for you by being trite."